# MySQL - How to run multiple update queries in one line?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET password = '$new_password' WHERE temp_url = '$temp_code';";

$sql = "UPDATE user SET temp_url = '' WHERE user_name = '$user_name_frmdb';";
```

How can I run the two update queries in one line?

Comment: Do they both work on the same row even though the where clause is different?

Comment: According to newfurniturey this is not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12830973/381802

Comment: @cxminer thats not entirely applicable to this question. For the old `mysql_*` api yes its not supported by mysqli supports mutliple queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php and the OP didnt mention which api they use. So it is supported and possible.

Comment: i hope Mysqli will support but i don`t know how to write that

Comment: I appologize, Hanky is right, it is possible using mysqli_multi_query(), please refer to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549284/updating-multiple-mysql-records-using-one-mysqli-query-call-in-php

Comment: Why do you want to? Which mysql query library are you using? And, as @Hanky웃Panky asks, is this the same row you're working on?

Comment: @sanso13527 just accept my answer if it was helpful

Comment: It's a bit unclear whether you want to combine the two queries into a single SQL query, or to have a way to run the two queries as two queries but atomically.  Could you clarify whether you are affecting a single row with the two queries?

Comment: you can connect to database using mysqli to run this query, Mysqli extention should be installed to make it working                   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

Comment: @ Avinash Babu sorry its not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Using Mysqli extention you can implement, you can run multiple queries using mysqli_multi_query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET password = '$new_password' WHERE temp_url = '$temp_code';";
$sql .= "UPDATE user SET temp_url = '' WHERE user_name = '$user_name_frmdb';";

// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $sql)) {
    // Query successful
}
```

Comment: Separate the queries with a semi-colon `;` and fix the syntax errors

Comment: i have updated the sql string, you need to use that, make sure you have installed mysqli & connection is running on mysqli

Comment: i tryed
$new_password = $_POST['Password'];
 $sql="Update user SET password = '$new_password' WHERE temp_url='$temp_code'";
 $sql.="Update user SET temp_url = '' WHERE user_name='$user_name_frmdb'";
  
  if (mysqli_multi_query($conDB,$sql))
{
echo "ok";
}

But its not working

Comment: @Hanky could you approve my edit so we can get rid of syntax errors and so the semi colon is shown

Comment: add semi colon after first query within mysql string  $sql="Update user SET password = '$new_password' WHERE temp_url='$temp_code' ; ";                                       $sql.="Update user SET temp_url = '' WHERE user_name='$user_name_frmdb'";